# Stopwatch on status/ notification bar

Tags: android, android-notifications, stopwatch

I'm able to use stopwatch / timer in an activity. BUT how can I show stopwatch also in notification bar ?

I have `starttime` and `elapsedtime` values, so:

- How to import/ show working stopwatch on notification bar ?
- How to continue stopwatch on notification bar  even if app closed ?

Comment: NotificationManager + Service

Comment: Are there any example to use them with a dynamic content ( stopwatch ) I may show a static text  in notificationbar but how to do it with dynamic one ? and I dont know how to implent service and stopwatch too.

Comment: Re-submit the same Notification with the same ID with new information. It will replace the existing one. Essentially you would be firing a notification every second, so don't use sound or vibration. You can probably mark it as ongoing as well.

Comment: check this link http://thorbek.net/online/2013/12/09/alarm-with-countdown-in-the-notification-bar/